# Error when uploading Xamarin UI Test in .NET 8

Tags: xamarin.uitest, .net-8.0, xamarin-test-cloud, appcenter

I've got a Xamarin UI test project that I've just updated to .NET 8 (from 4.6.1). I've updated the nuget packages to the latest version also. The tests build and run locally with no issue.

Packages:

- Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk 17.8.0
- NUnit 3.14.0
- NUnit3TestAdapter 4.5.0
- Xamarin.UITest 4.3.1

I'm trying to upload with the app center cli using the command "appcenter test run uitest". I've got the "uitest-tools-dir" parameter set to the build folder of the project as this spits out "test-cloud.exe" from the Xamarin.UITest package.

When running the command in powershell, I get the following error :

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at Xamarin.UITest.CLI.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

- That seemed a simple enough error to fix, right? I've tried adding the below to my csproj. This just results in a warning icon in visual studio under the dependencies tree for that reference.

  ```
  <ItemGroup>
      <Reference Include="netstandard" />
  </ItemGroup>
  ```
- Tried adding a reference to the NETStandard.Library nuget package
- Adding this to my csproj:

  ```
  <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
  ```

None of these have worked (still no netstandard dll in my build output). I'm wondering if I'm missing something simple here? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, they have not yet configured Xamarin.UITest to .Net 8 and that work is being worked on now in order to make Xamarin.UITest compatible with .Net 8. However, it is compatible with .Net 6 and you should be able to change your project to .Net 6 till Xamarin.UITest does the updates needed for .Net 8

Comment: Yeah I got in contract with support and they confirmed that .NET is not supported with app center test - they advised to use .NET 4.8 for the time being. Thanks for the reply.